# Pymc Input dimension mis-match

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pymc3, pymc

I am having an error in Pymc that I can't understand.
[image]

I think is related to dimensions of the of a dot product (see     logit_p = pm.Deterministic("logit_p",  X_data * beta)
), but I double checked and it makes sense. X_data has 198x37 and I specify that beta has shape 37 (is one dimensional). What is the problem here? Can you someone please help me ?

```html
with pm.Model() as model:
    X_data = pm.Data("X", standard_scaler.transform(X))
    y_data = pm.Data("y", y.values)
    priors_for_covariates = []
    priors_for_covariates.append(pm.Uniform("intersect", 1, 100))
    for i,e in enumerate(round_1_stats_column_for_b):
        priors_for_covariates.append(pm.Uniform(e, 1, 100))
    beta = pm.Normal("beta", mu=0, tau=0.0001, shape=(X.shape[1]))
    logit_p = pm.Deterministic("logit_p",  X_data * beta)
    print(X_data.shape)
    likelihood = pm.Bernoulli("likelihood", logit_p=logit_p, observed=y_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Got working by substituying this line:

logit_p = pm.Deterministic("logit_p",  X_data * beta)

for:

logit_p = pm.math.dot(X_data , beta)